# matlab solve s. of nonlinear e.; sth. equal to R nleqslv(, control=list(allowSingular=TRUE))

Tags: r, matlab, solver

### Question

**What is the equivilant of R code:`nleqslv(xstart,f, method="Newton", control=list(allowSingular=TRUE))` in matlab?** Particularly, how can something like this `control=list(allowSingular=TRUE)` in matlab be achieved?

### Background

My research is based on research from somebody who is programming in R. I am using matlab. I am trying to transfer his code into matlab. I am stuck, because I cannot solve an equation which is solved like this, `nleqslv(xstart,f, method="Newton", control=list(allowSingular=TRUE))` in R. I believe the important part is `control=list(allowSingular=TRUE))`.

---

This is an **extract of R Code** which I modified to make it work without the rest of the code.

```
if(!require(pracma)){install.packages("pracma")}
if(!require(nleqslv)){install.packages("nleqslv")}
library(pracma)
library(nleqslv)

n = 4
c = 2
m = 10
rest = c(0.4089769, 0.8830174, 0.9404673, 0.0455565, 0.5281055)
alpha = c(-0.751574, -1.763454,  2.515028, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
LstarC = rbind(c( -0.751574,0,0,0),
               c(-1.763454,0,0,0),
               c(2.515028,0,0,0),
               c(0,0,0,0),
               c(0,0,0,0),
               c(0,0,0,0),
               c(0,0,0,0),
               c(0,0,0,0),
               c(0,0,0,0),
               c(0,0,0,0))
bstar = rbind(c(1.000000e+00),
              c(5.551115e-17),
              c(0.000000e+00),
              c(0.000000e+00))

fnbeta2 <- function(x, c, rest, alpha, LstarC, n, bstar, m) {
  y <- numeric(n+c-1) 

  y[1] <- sum(x[1:(n+c-1)])+sum(rest)
  y[2] <- sum(x[1:(n+c-1)]^2)+sum(rest^2)-m
  y[3] <- x[1:(n+c-1)]%*%alpha[1:(n+c-1)]^2-m*bstar[c]+rest%*%alpha[(n+c):m]^2

  for(i in seq(from=4,to=4+c-2)){
    y[i] <- x[1:(n+c-1)]%*%LstarC[1:(n+c-1),i-3]+rest%*%LstarC[(n+c):m,i-3]
  }

  return(y)
}
f <- function(x) fnbeta2(x, c, rest, alpha, LstarC, n, bstar, m)
xstart = ones(1,5)
xval2 <- nleqslv(xstart,f, method="Newton", control=list(allowSingular=TRUE))
xval2$x
f(xval2$x)
```

---

This is my attempt at transferring the code into **matlab**.

```
n = 4;
c = 2;
m = 10;
rest = [0.4089769; 0.8830174; 0.9404673; 0.0455565; 0.5281055];
alpha = [-0.751574; -1.763454;  2.515028; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0];
LstarC = [ -0.751574,0,0,0;
    -1.763454,0,0,0; ...
    2.515028,0,0,0; ...
    0,0,0,0; ...
    0,0,0,0; ...
    0,0,0,0; ...
    0,0,0,0; ...
    0,0,0,0; ...
    0,0,0,0; ...
    0,0,0,0];
bstar = [1.000000e+00; 5.551115e-17; 0.000000e+00; 0.000000e+00];

xstart =ones(n+c-1, 1);
f = @(x) fnbeta( x, c, rest, alpha, LstarC, n, bstar, m );
xval = fsolve(f,xstart)
```

fnbeta in a seperate .m file

```
function [ y ] = fnbeta( x, c, rest, alpha, LstarC, n, bstar, m )
y = zeros(n+c-1,1);
y(1) = sum( x( 1:(n+c-1)), 1 ) + sum(rest);
y(2) = sum( x( 1:(n+c-1), 1 ).^2 ) + sum( rest.^2 ) - m;
y(3) = x( 1:(n+c-1), 1 )' * alpha( 1:(n+c-1) ).^2 + ...
    rest' * alpha((n+c):m).^2 - m * bstar(c);
for j=4:(4+c-2)
    y(j) = x(1:(n+c-1), 1)' * LstarC( 1:(n+c-1), j-3 ) + ...
        rest' * LstarC((n+c):m, j-3);
end
end
```

---

Matlab traceback

```
Solver stopped prematurely.

fsolve stopped because it exceeded the function evaluation limit,
options.MaxFunctionEvaluations = 500 (the default value).
```

I believe my `fnbeta` or better my anonymous function `f` is fine because it gives me `0,0,..` when passing in the result R calculates. Furthermore R gives me only good results if `control=list(allowSingular=TRUE)` is specified:
[image]
[image]

---

### Update

changing the solver has improved my results, but the deviations are in the region of 10^-3 which I do not find acceptable, because R has gotten so much closer

```
options = optimoptions('lsqnonlin', 'Algorithm', 'levenberg-marquardt', 'ScaleProblem' ,'jacobian')
xval = lsqnonlin(f,xstart,[],[],options)
```

Comment: You should first try and see what's going on when you use `allowSingular=TRUE`. Use the argument `jacobian=TRUE` in the call to `nleqslv` to get the final jacobian. Display the complete return value of `nleqslv`. The last two columns of the jacobian are identical. There is something seriously wrong with your system of equations.

Comment: In addition try `Broyden` in the same way. You will see that the final approximation of the Jacobian is not as bad as the one with `Newton`. You really need to find out what is not right and where.

Comment: There is no implementation of Broyden in Matlab, right? Should I just use some code I find if I Google it?

Comment: I haven't got a clue. I know nothing about Matlab. You should first analyse your system of equations for errors or mistakes before continuing. A singular Jacobian is not a trivial matter.

Comment: I'm certain there is something wrong with your system. Instead of `Newton` try `Broyden`. You will get a solution completely different from the one shown by the Newton method.

Comment: Something funny in the `for` loop in function `fnbeta2`. The loop stops when `i` equals 4. This means that `y[5]` is never given a value and so remains 0.

Comment: yep, saw that too. It is part of a larger optimization and this is the first iteration, the first time the function fnbeta is created

Comment: @Bhas It is true that Boyden and Newton method find different results. But both results plugged into f give sth close to zero, therefore I am not certain it is sth with the system. I believe it is perfectly normal that different algorithms find different solutions as long as both are really solutions, which is the case.